# xsd -> WCF models

Tags: c#, wcf, xsd, asmx

Are there any tool which can generate DTOs which has been decorated with the WCF attributes using a XSD file?

Would be great when migrating from an traditional ASMX service to a WCF service.

Comment: It is not required to decorate your DTOs with WCF specific attributes anymore (since .NET 3.5 SP1). A POCO would work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Add the [XmlSerializerFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.xmlserializerformatattribute.aspx) attribute to your service contract, then you can use your existing ASMX DTOs unchanged.